# How bazel genrule srcs works under the hood

Tags: bazel

Well, I'm trying to figure out how `srcs` works for `genrule`, I have the following:

```
genrule(
    name = "flutter_build_android",
     srcs = [
        "//:genfiles"
    ],
    outs = ["android/mobile.apk"],
    cmd_bash = "ls -ltr && flutter build apk > $@",
    tags = ["local"]
)
```

`//:genfiles` is a filegroup using `glob`:

```
filegroup(
    name = "genfiles",
    srcs = glob(["lib/**","assets/**", "pubspec.yaml"])
)
```

When executing my `genrule` what I expect is only files under `://genfiles` label should be returned, but it is returning all folders under my root project:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that the genrule is tagged with `local`, and local means

```
precludes the action or test from being remotely cached, remotely executed, or run inside the sandbox
```

https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common.tags

Sandboxing is what prevents an action from seeing files that aren't declared as dependencies (i.e. in `srcs` here). Without the sandbox, the action sees everything.

```
$ tree
.
├── BUILD
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
└── WORKSPACE

0 directories, 5 files

$ cat BUILD

genrule(
  name = "gen_foo",
  outs = ["foo"],
  srcs = ["file1"],
  cmd = "echo ----- ; ls ; echo ----- ; wc -l $< > $@",
  # tags = ["local"],
)

$ bazel build foo
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (5 packages loaded, 9 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Executing genrule //:gen_foo:
-----
bazel-out
external
file1
-----
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.379s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions

# edit BUILD to restore the local tag

$ cat BUILD

genrule(
  name = "gen_foo",
  outs = ["foo"],
  srcs = ["file1"],
  cmd = "echo ----- ; ls ; echo ----- ; wc -l $< > $@",
  tags = ["local"],
)

$ bazel build foo
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (5 packages loaded, 9 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Executing genrule //:gen_foo:
-----
BUILD
WORKSPACE
bazel-out
external
file1
file2
file3
local-spawn-runner.8714966150718292736
-----
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.350s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then, in case of using `local` tag `srcs` is ignored because I can have access to all files under root directory. Am I right ?

Comment: `srcs` can also contain generated files from other targets, so it's important to list those even with the local tag. Otherwise, bazel won't know to build those before running the genrule. There are also finer-grained tags like `no-sandbox`, `no-cache`, `no-remote-cache`, `no-remote-exec`, `no-remote` you can use depending on what you need.